# Bonus dice and flurries

Tags: exalted, exalted-2e

A simple Exalted 2e rules question here that I feel like I should know the answer to.

I have an 8-die dex + melee pool.  I do a three-attack flurry.  That's three attacks, one at 5 dice, one at 4, and one at 3.

I perform a two-die stunt while making this attack.  Does my three-attack flurry go 7/4/3, or does it go 7/6/5? (I believe it is 7/6/5 but I'm not positive)

Instead of stunting, I spend two motes on First Melee Excellency.  Does my three-attack flurry go 7/4/3, or does it go 7/6/5? (Again, I believe it is 7/6/5 but I'm not positive)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Flurry answer:** I'm pretty sure excellencies apply to individual rolls, so it would go 7/4/3. Luckily [Infinite Melee Mastery](http://rathess.xi.co.nz/exalted/index.php/Charms:Infinite_%28Ability%29_Mastery_%28Solar%29), or similar, will make applying two dice to the entire flurry free once you can get it.

**Simple stunt answer:** Stunts have to apply to entire flurries, otherwise the game breaks. This is because the ability to flurry every individual attack leads to the ability to gain enough motes to pay for an action long perfect every action, and that means nobody can ever die.

**Complex stunt answer:** Once you've said that the attacker can stunt each attack separately, then it stands to reason the defender can stunt each defense separately. Assuming your following the core books definition of 2 dot stunts as merely bringing the environment into play, most players can routinely get them and pay for their perfect defenses. If you don't follow the core book on stunts to prevent this, then the next question is if you use unexpected attacks. If you do, then players need to be able to combo their defense or a surprise attack will kill them. This means that any attacker with sufficient stealth and the endurance to survive until your players' starting willpower runs out will kill them, which generally isn't considered fun. If you don't use the stealth rules, then, because of overdrive, nobody needs to combo every action once combat gets going. If you still allow your players to get one dot stunts routinely they can survive forever as long as they can meet the condition of the cost lowering charms on their perfects, which in at least some cases is pretty easy. Further, once you start restricting your players stunts charms like [Tragic love amusement](http://rathess.xi.co.nz/exalted/index.php/Charms:Tragic_Love_Amusement), which give stunt bonuses, become much higher valued.

Comment: Yeah, but you'll never recover enough willpower to keep using the combo that allows you to use that perfect and any other charms every round. But hey, if you want to do nothing but flail at me while dodging my attacks, so be it. Exalted is a very Perfect or Die game. :)

Comment: Okay, I'll admit I was being briefer than I could have. How about this formulation of the first point: If you can stunt each attack in the flurry then you should be able to stunt each defense against each attack in the flurry. If you can do that you can pay the 3 motes to perfect each attack individually and that means nobody will ever die. It gets worse when you start including charms like Lightspeed Body Dynamics, near perfects, and have a full 2/7 defense.

Comment: I'll happily accept that, but I'd also point out if you're handing out 2 die stunts like candy then you're setting yourself up for a problem.

Comment: The answer above now reflects our discussion. If I still haven't covered some possibilities, I'd be happy to, just mention them.

Answer (score 2):

I would rule that any enhancements that apply to one attack apply to one attack and not all attacks in that turn.  So, I would rule that the two-die stun could be applied to either the 5, the 4, or the 3, so one could choose from 7/4/3, 5/6/3, or 5/4/5.  Otherwise, the three-attack flurry becomes rather gross as an ability -- not necessary a bad thing ^_~

Comment: I'd agree unless the stunt would benefit/apply to all the attacks (which would depend largely on the nature of the stunt).

Comment: I have always made the players stunt each attack in the flurry, and not the whole thing. You could miss your first attack and then your stunt no longer makes sense. So instead of one long stunt action you can react to dice rolls and play that out accordingly.